# Creating multiple items (tables, columns, measures) in Power BI using DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

We create a monthly report in Power BI which requires creating multiple new tables, columns and measures from the data we import. Currently, the instructions for creating these tables is done manually, where we click on the new table or new column or new measure button and paste in the DAX code for that individual item.

I am a DAX newbie and was hoping to streamline the process. Can we create a multiple line DAX code that will create the tables as well as the measures and columns (in the correct table) that we only have to enter once?

Here is what I am asking for in psuedo-code:

```
Create Table A
Create Column 1 in Table B
Create Column 2 in Table B
Create Measure X in Table B
...
Create Measure Z in Table B
Create Table C
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible. I'm not sure exactly how it would streamline your process though. You can copy and paste queries and tables between files.

Comment: you can't create a measure when you create a table. the column needs to be created first.

Comment: I've never heard of any Power BI solution remotely like what you describe. It sounds like whoever designed it has totally missed the core concepts of Power BI.  I would suggest slowing down and getting some expert advice before you waste more time.

Comment: I may have state this unclearly. Currently, we create a few tables from the data imported, then add columns and measures. Right now the process involves clicking on the table, choosing create new measure, and pasting in the code we reuse each month for the report. There are several dozen columns and measures we create in a few tables and it is time consuming and tedious to create one by one. I was hoping to streamline things where we can just paste in the code all at once.

Comment: A couple of things to think about. Measures are shown under a table in the interface, but they are really independent of tables. You could create a dummy table and attach all the "added" measure to it so you would not have to create them every month. If you "create the tables from the data imported" you should be able to structure them as M queries, which would work automatically if your tables always had the same structure.